# Login Screen Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing an app which consists of a login and registration process. So, when I searched I found a good login page design of another app which is shown in the image.

[image]

Will anybody help me to attain the same design as shown in the image? 
How to make a transparent layer in front of the picture?

Comment: Its not a transparent layer. Its just a background image with labels and text fields on top of it.

Comment: your question is way to broad. Start for yourself with something and then ask specific questions, e.g. on how to make a layer transparent or something.

Comment: may a transparent  background will work for you, start you app in android material design

Comment: Before asking a question Please do search on google .Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

In this login page they are using background image and on that background image you can set App logo and text fields

Answer (score -1):

You can design the image like this fading effect. It can be easily obtained by using photoshop. And then you have to set that image as the background of your layout. All Done !!!